# Very Important question. Limiting distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have an exam in the morning and there is still one question I cannot do.

> $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid random variables each having distribution with density $f_{X_i}(x;\theta)= 1/\theta$, for $x \in [0,\theta]$ where $\theta>0$ compute the CDF of the random variable $\max(X_1,\ldots X_n)$ and prove that 
>   $n(\theta-\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)) \to W$ in distribution and state the CDF of $W$.

How can I do this? I have worked out that the CDF of $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is $ (x/\theta)^n$ but that is all :(

Thanks.

Comment: The TeX was messed up (I think you'll learn some things from the new source; also, there's no need to put tildes between everything :)) so I tried to fix it. I know nothing about probability theory so you should check that I didn't change your meaning. Also consider making the title more descriptive.

Comment: Good luck with your exam. I bet this question is not among the question in the exam tomorrow.

Comment: Are you sure your CDF of max() is correct? I find a different answer starting from $P(max(X_1,\dots,X_n)>c) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i >c, X_j\le c \;\;\forall j \neq i)$.

Comment: @EmreA Your derivation is incorrect: LHS > RHS for all $n>1$.

Comment: @ErickWong, I don't see it, why?

Comment: @EmreA What if $X_i > c$ for more than one $i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already worked out the CDF of $\max(X_1,...,X_n)$.  Now just find the CDF of $n(\theta-\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$ (use the definition of CDF, it's not hard) and take the limit as $n\to\infty$ (use $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+x/n)^n = e^x$).

Comment: Thanks, so obvious now how to do it... but my calculations are going wrong, I worked out the CDF of the second one but i get $\ 1-(1-x/{n\theta})^n $  so then $\ 1-e^{-x/\theta}?$

Comment: Looks about right to me.  Note that the your CDF for $\max(X_1,...,X_n)$ is valid for $0 \le x \le \theta$, which makes the later CDF valid for $0 \le x \le n\theta$.  As $n \to \infty$ this range of validity extends to all of $[0,\infty)$.